# I am getting two different answers for a basic integration problem

Tags: calculus, integration

I was solving a question of application of integrals (to find area under a curve)
when I had to integrate $\displaystyle \int_{-3}^{-1} (x+2)dx$.
Now I split the integral as : $\displaystyle\int_{-3}^{-1} xdx + 2\int_{-3}^{-1} dx$ and got the result as 
$\displaystyle \left[\dfrac{x^2}{2}+2x\right]_{-3}^{-1}$. The final answer I got was wrong so I tried again as:
$\displaystyle \int (x+2)dx = \int ydy $   where $\displaystyle y = x+2
\Rightarrow \dfrac{y^2}{2} = \dfrac{(x+2)^2}{2}$.
Now when I expand this result I do not end up with $\displaystyle \dfrac{x^2}{2} +2x$.
Why is there a difference in the answers?

Comment: Learn [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your posts on this site.

Comment: But you are finding area so answer is the same which is 0

Comment: They only differ by a constant but it doesn't matter as it cancels out.

Answer (score 2):

Two antiderivatives of a same function can differ by a constant. 
Here $\dfrac{(x+2)^2}{2}=\left(\dfrac{x^2}{2}+2x\right)+2$ and the constant is $2$. But the two methods give the same result for the integral since 
$\left[\dfrac{(x+2)^2}{2}\right]_{-3}^{-1}= \left[\dfrac{x^2}{2}+2x\right]_{-3}^{-1}+2-2$.